# Auto formatting for opening brackets in vscode stopped working TS/JS

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, auto-indent

When declaring a function or if statement in javascript or typescript file vscode stopped "opening" up the brackets on enter. So when the marker is between the brackets and i hit enter on the following exampels it just adds a new line.

```
// pipe symbol is the marker
const myFunction = () => {|}

// expected result
const myFunction = () => {
  |
}

// result I get
const myFunction = () => {
|}

// same thing eg. if statements
if (...) {|}

// expected result
if (...) {
  |
}

// result I get
if (...) {
|}
```

- I have prettier as default formatter
- Formatting work "on save" or "shift+alt+f" (Windows) so Prettier works.
- I have setting for autoIndent = "full"
- I have vscode synced to another computer that now have the same issue.
- I have uninstalled and reinstalled Prettier

The issue is maybe a week old, I cannot recall changing any settings or installing any new extensions. But some how I must have messed it up :/

Any idéas out there?

## Some updates

**Help: About**

```
Version: 1.81.1 (user setup)
Commit: 6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794
Date: 2023-08-09T22:22:42.175Z
Electron: 22.3.18
ElectronBuildId: 22689846
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
```

**TypeScript: Select TypeScript Version...**
Use vscode´s version 5.1.6

- I have tried to disable prettier
- It is the same issue in both js and ts files
- Same issue if I reload vscode with all extensions disabled

Comment: what if you create a new and empty [profile](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles) (which is a simple way of testing with settings and other config "reset")

Comment: @starball that seems to have done the trick. I created a new profile and unchecked the box for extensions and with that profile opening brackets work as expected.

I tried to disable all extensions in the default profile but that wont fix the issue in the default profile.

Comment: if you unchecked the extensions box, that means it uses extensions from the default profile (it'll say so beside the checkbox). so the problem is either in your settings.json, or in your keybindings.json. please paste both into your question post.

Comment: Thanks for the directions, the issue was

"editor.language.brackets": []

In settings.json, removing that solved the issue. Big thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes it does answer my question!